# $n^{\alpha}U_{(1)} \to 0$ almost surely for any $\alpha < 0.5$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Let $U_i$ be a sequence of identically distributed independent random variables with following density function $f(x) = 2x \ \ x \in[0,1]$ and $0$ everywhere else. I need to show $n^{\alpha}U_{(1)} \to 0$ almost surely for any $\alpha < 0.5$.

$U_{(1)} = min(U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n)$

My attempt:
I have tried to use Borel-Cantelli lemma and got the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(n^\alpha U_{(1)} \geq \epsilon) = \sum (1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{n^{2\alpha}})^n $

If I show the above series converges, I couldn't prove above series converges.

Comment: Are you sure that you want $\alpha > \frac12$ - I think that series only converges for $\alpha < \frac12$.

Comment: Sorry.  I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1-t \leq e^{-t}$ for any $t \geq 0$  $\sum e^{-cn^{s}}<\infty$ for any $c,s >0$. [For any positive integer $k$ we have $e^{-cn^{s}} \leq \frac  1{(cn^{s})^{k}} {k!}$ choose $k$ such that $sk>1$].

Comment: I got similar expression. I couldn't show $\sum e^{-cn^s} < \infty$

Comment: @Tiramisu I have added some more steps.

Comment: Thank you @kaviramamurthy